# Is my modulo use wrong or is there a Math.floor rounding error happening with my seconds to minutes calculation?

Tags: javascript

**SOLVED:** Seems it's a problem that only exists in Codepen. Running code in a different environment didn't reproduce the problem.

---

Am writing code to split seconds into years, days, minutes, seconds. I'm getting some unexpected results: eg 3600 seconds comes out as 1 hour. But 3599 seconds comes out as 60 minutes and 59 seconds.

Firstly, there should never be 60 minutes. This should be 1 hour. But that aside the actual result is wrong.

Is there some error in my calculation logic, or is there a funky rounding error going on using modulo and Math.floor? Thanks!

```
  function convertFromSeconds(time) {

  const minute = 60
  const hour = 60 * minute; //3600
  const day = 24 * hour; // 86400
  const year = 365 * day //31536000
  
  const years = Math.floor(time / year)
  const days = Math.floor((time % year) / day)
  const hours = Math.floor((time % day) / hour)
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % hour) / minute)
  const seconds = time % minute;

  // Rest of code formats the above result into a string for output
}
```

```js
function convertFromSeconds(time) {

  const minute = 60
  const hour = 60 * minute; //3600
  const day = 24 * hour; // 86400
  const year = 365 * day //31536000

  const years = Math.floor(time / year)
  const days = Math.floor((time % year) / day)
  const hours = Math.floor((time % day) / hour)
  const minutes = Math.floor((time % hour) / minute)
  const seconds = time % minute;

  // Rest of code formats the above result into a string for output

  return { years, days, hours, minutes, seconds }
}

console.log('3600:', convertFromSeconds(3600))
console.log('3599:', convertFromSeconds(3599))
```

Comment: @Martu - running your code with a `time` input of 3599, I get 0 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds, as presumably intended. So I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Added a snippet with your unchanged code but with an added return. Showing expected output. Possibly a problem in your later 'formatting'?

Comment: I am not an experat in integer math in JavaScript, but I guess technically there could be a rounding error. `3599 / 3600` ist using floating point devision. If the result cannot be represented, in might be rounded to `1.0` before appliying `Math.floor`. However, `3600` is a rather small number, so I wouldn't expect such issue here.

Comment: Also if you'll ever have negative timestamps (anything before Jan 1 1970 if you're using unix timestamps) you'll need to use [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) not `Math.floor` to avoid rounding in the wrong direction.